# behavior of var function

Tags: clojure

I have two somewhat related problems, shown by the following:

```
user=> (if (symbol? 5) (meta (var 5)) 5)
CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Symbol, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:6) 
user=> (defn dometa [x] (if (symbol? x) (meta (var x)) x))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: x in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:7) 
user=>
```

In the first case, since 5 is not a symbol I would not expect `(meta (var 5))` to be evaluated, but it is (or at least that's the way it seems to me).

In the second case, if I want to place the first expression in a function, and parameterize the value being tested, the (var ...) function no longer works.

Comment: `var` is not a function, it is a special form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Var object is [looked up at compile time](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L607).  For the behaviour I'm inferring from your examples, you should use `find-var`.

```
user=> (if (symbol? 5) (meta (find-var 5)) 5)
5
user=> (defn dometa [x] (if (symbol? x) (meta (find-var x)) x))
#'user/dometa
```

Comment: You probably want `resolve`, not `find-var`. I'd never heard of `find-var` before, but it looks like a lower-level version of `resolve`.